# Wsus update status

Tags: wsus

i have an issue with my wsus server, when i run a report for a specific update i got that its installed for some clients, not installed for other and for the remain i got no status.

when i check the client  i find that the required update is installed.

if i check another one from the clients with "no status " i found that its not installed.

please suggest or drop any comment, since i got this entire environment after the previous admin resign with no document left.

Comment: What is it you're asking for?  Do you need help getting the clients to update?  Do you need help configuring WSUS?  There isn't really a question in there as it's worded now.  Could you edit your "question" to make it clearer about what you're asking help with?

Comment: i have working wsus, which i am working on now, and it was required to deploy a security update for win xp clients. and i create a group to test that patch deployment.

now i got many of them with no status for that specif update ?


since you are talking about configuring wsus, is there any steps to check in a live enviroment to confirm that every thing is ok

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is the exact same update? It could be that a different update has superseded the one that you are looking at, making it not installed but also not needed.

Comment: no its a new update security update for win xp

Answer (score 0):

Because computers normally report their status to the WSUS server only once per day (perhaps less if they ever get turned off or taken home), a computer will ordinarily show "No Status" for any update that is new since the last time it has reported status to the server.

WSUS can be frustrating in that it will show you problems without providing any explanation, nor any real-time means of resolution.  It is imperfect, but it is also far better than nothing.

On what date was the specific update in question released?  Are the computers that report "no status" for this update reporting no status for a large number of updates over multiple dates, or just the updates released on the most recent Patch Tuesday?  Are these computers configured for automatic updates or do they require manual intervention?

Comment: the are configured, but it seem the WUA need manual intervention;

Is there any way to refresh the information "PC, update " .

i noticed that i have many pcs with duplicated ip, i dont know is this because the ip is dynamic.

or its an old information ??